# Layer toggle in kicad

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, kicad

Is there a simple way to toggle `kicad` layers? For now, I am able only to manually tick the respective layer boxes. Is there a way to optimize this task, e.g. layer profiles?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the PNS router, before you begin placing a new track, press the `v` key to toggle between your paired layers.  Correspondingly, after you begin laying the track, `v` will place a via (and switch you to the paired layer).

If you wanted to switch to a specific layer, the default hotkeys are:

- Top Copper -- **PgUp**
- Bottom Copper -- **PgDown**
- Inner Layer 1 -- **F5**
- Inner Layer 2 -- **F6**
- Inner Layer 3 -- **F7**
- Inner Layer 4 -- **F8**
- Inner Layer 5 -- **Shift-F5**
- Inner Layer 6 -- **Shift-F6**

You can shift up and down layers with `+` and `-`

Comment: Can you change the layer of a track you just started (and realised it should go to a different layer) without aborting routing first?

Comment: @silverdr No, because the routing is explicitly tied to the starting net and its associated layer

Comment: this is kind of disappointing. "The other software", which I am now in the process of leaving behind makes no problem with that. You start routing, you realise you used the wrong layer so you change it on-the-fly with one click. I get that KiCAD still doesn't allow that.